# Add to cart validation in WooCommerce is working only when the cart is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried to add the following code for a testing purpose on function.php

```
 function filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation( $passed, 
$product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = null, $variations = null ) {
          wc_add_notice( __( 'Please enter a value into the text flowers label', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'filter_woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 10, 5 );
```

so that on every click in the add to cart button it throws error.

but this works only if the cart has already been added with some products,if the cart is empty error is not throwing